# Remove Perl module from child stack

Tags: perl, memory, fork

I have a daemon which loads DBI (DBD::mysql) and then forks child processes. I'd like to prevent the DBI module from being in memory in the forked child processes.

So something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect(db_info);

my $pid = fork();
if($pid){

# The forked process here should not have DBI loaded

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  It is a very odd request.

Comment: Sure, I have a server daemon which forks of child processes. The chld processes do not need access to DBI, but the main process does because it uses a databases to to load a list of acceptable peer host IP's. So before forking off a separate process to communicate with over the socket, the main thread validates it is an acceptable IP to communicate with.

Comment: Do you have proof that the DBI is causing you to have memory problems or is this just a hunch?

Comment: Well it isn't really causing "problems" per say. It's just that it appears to be copied in memory when doing an lsof of the child process. Since there are hundreds of child processes, it looks like the best one to try to tackle (since it has the largest footprint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading a module is to execute it like a script. There's absolutely no difference between a module and a script to Perl. To unload a module, one would need to undo the effects of running it. That can't be done mechanically, and it's not feasible to do manually.

The simplest solution would to be to have the child `exec` something. It could even be the script you are already running.

```
exec($^X, $0, '--child', @args)
```

The child can be given access to the socket by binding it to the child's fd 0 (stdin) and fd 1 (stdout).

Comment: While this would solve the stated problem, it's worth noting that unless the child is very small it will chew more time and memory to `exec` a new Perl process than to make a fork.

Comment: @Schwern, What are you talking about? You can't `exec` unless you do the fork. Yes, it will take up a bit more memory, but really, the OP doesn't want to share any with the parent anyway.

Comment: I was referring to fork + exec vs just forking.  And it's not yet clear why the OP wants to do what they're asking.

Comment: Since this is a networking daemon, the child would need to have access to the socket, or rather, the "accepted" client of the main socket. The whole purpose of this is to keep the memory usage low per child process, so as far as I can tell this would increase the usage. Right?

Comment: @GoldenNewby, You can't have a new interpreter and not spend any memory to get it. It's up to you to decide if not using more memory is more important than not having DBI loaded in the child. In the end, it might actually use up less memory. It depends on how many pages you can keep shared, and how much less you can avoid loading in the child.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, As for access to the socket, just tie the child's STDIN and STDOUT to it.

Comment: I follow your thinking now. So basically create a new process, which is technically the child (but not forked per conventionally), and then make it so that new process's STDIN/STDOUT are tied to the socket. Any hints as to how to do that?

Comment: @GoldenNewby, no, continue to create the child using `fork`. Assigning a file handle to a a descriptor is a form of an operation called "dup", and `open` can be use to do that. (Modes `>&=` and `<&=`, IIRC)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that easily unless you put the load after the fork.  But to do that you have to not use `use`.  Do this instead:

```
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid) {
     # child
} else {
     require DBI;
     import DBI;
}
```

That should prevent the DBI module from loading until after the fork.  The `use` routine essentially does a require/import but inside a BEGIN {} block which is why you have to not use it.

Comment: The problem with that is that the main process will spawn child processes as they are needed, not at a fixed moment in the script.

Comment: You call `import` as an indirect object method?!? Yuck!

Comment: @Joel Berger, It's not like it's a normal method call (since you can call it even the package has no `import` method), and `import` is documented in perlfunc. While I normally go "yuck!" at indirect method calls, this is the one time I do not.

Comment: @ikegami `import` is a method call. To write it as `import DBI` implies that it's a function. To put it next to `require DBI`, a built-in function call, is downright misleading. That `import` has a magical default implementation doesn't change that it's a method called on the class `DBI`, not a built in function nor a function in the current namespace.

Comment: @Schwern, your reply is only relevant if you deny the exitence of indirect method calls and if you mistakenly believe it matters if someone implies that `import` is a function. It's perfectly fine to see it as a function leading to a method call. It's definitely NOT a normal method call despite your claims. It actually behaves like a function (`sub { my $method = $_[0]->can('import'); goto &$method if $method; }`), and it's perfectly fine to think of it as a function since there's no problem in doing that.

Comment: @ikegami There is no function wrapper, it's special cased in the method dispatcher, but let's examine this. If the default `import` was done via an empty `UNIVERSAL::import`, would you make the same argument? What if `can` and `isa` were done like `import`, would you write them differently? Is that `import` has a default implementation important to convey to the user, more than that it's an inherited method call?  Does showing it like a function call convey that information?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but unfortunately it wouldn't solve the problem I'm trying to address.

Comment: @ikegami and @Schwern: the reason I changed the use into 'require/import' as written above is actually because it was only recently that the documentation for `use` changed to do it via the new MODULE->import call.  I was trying to stick with the direct reading I had done about it so as to avoid confusion.  But admittedly I hadn't run `perldoc -f use` on a more recent version where indeed it had changed.  5.8 and I think 5.10 still had import as a bare word.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a modern Linux system, then forks are COW (copy on write).  This means pages from the parent are only copied to the child's address space if they are modified by the parent or the child.  So, the DBI module is not in the memory of the forked child processes.

Perl 5 does not have any way of unloading modules from memory.  If you really need the children to have different code than the parent for some reason, you are better off separating that code out of the main code as its own script and then using [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) after the fork to run the child script.  This will be slower than normal forking since it has to compile the child code, so if you fork a lot, it might be better to have two scripts that talk to each other over sockets and have the "child" script pre-fork.

Comment: I'm not sure how well COW works with perl.  The perl executable can be COW, because it doesn't get modified.  Compiled Perl code, including loaded modules, is just data from the operating system's perspective.  It doesn't know that some data changes (variables) and some data *probably* doesn't (code).  It just knows that it has allocated perl memory and perl tries to change some of it.  Then again, I'm no memory allocation expert.

Comment: As far as I can tell from lsof the child process copies everything, not just things it modifies.

Comment: @Schwern COW is page based, so unless Perl 5 is storing Perl variables and code in the same pages (which I doubt), all of the code should be COW-safe. @GoldenNewby I don't understand how you are using `lsof`.  As far as I know `lsof` lists open files, not memory usage.  The child process will have all of the same filehandles the parent had, but that means nothing in terms of memory usage.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but doesn't the "mem" columns in lsof -pPID represent the libraries copied into memory for the running process? So perl    29732 root  mem    REG    202,2    81800 3526267 /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Storable/Storable.so would indicate the Storable module is using about 80KB of RAM?

Comment: Storable.so is a shared library. Shared libraries are only in memory once, no matter how many processes are using it. So, yes 80k is in use, but only 80k will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing now what you want to do with this, since there isn't a good way to unload modules i Perl, a good solution to the problem as to write an authentication server separate from the application server.  The application server asks the authentication server if an IP has permissions.  That way they remain in wholly separate processes.  This might also have security benefits, your application code can't access your authentication database.

Since any given application is likely to expand to the point where it needs a SQL database of its own, this exercise is probably futile, but your call.

This is a bunch of extra work and maintenance and complexity.  It's only worth while if it's causing you real memory problems, not just because it's bugs you.  Remember, RAM is very cheap.  Developer time is very expensive.

Comment: Well, for the project I am working on, RAM is something I have to keep in mind. Each child process (While using DBD::mysql) used about 10MB of RAM. So that means for every 100 processes, I need to pay for a gig of RAM, which comes out to about 20 cents per process (renting a dedi server). The project maintains thousands of these connections, so it can actually add up pretty quick. After removing direct access to MySQL, it halfed the usage.